# Parallel calculation on a sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

I have a large [numpy] vector X, and a comparison function `f(x,y)`. I need to find all the pairs of elements of X for which `f(X[I],X[j])<T` for some threshold T. This works well:

```
good_inds = {}
for i in range(0,len(X)):
   for j in range(x+1,len(X)):
       score = f(X[i],X[j])
       if score<T:
           good_inds[x,y] = score
```

This actually builds a dictionary which is a representation of a sparse matrix. The problem is that it's rather slow, and I wish to parallelise this process.
Please advise.

Comment: `x` and `y` are constants within the scope of this snippet, so why use a dictionary? Did you mean `x --> X[i]` and `y --> X[j]`?

Comment: answers to this sort of question will be strongly dependant on what `f` does, e.g. what sort of constraints can be exploited.  Roland's answer is great if there's nothing more known about the problem, but you'd get much more relevant answers if you said that `X` and `Y` are both `numpy` arrays and `f` a simple algebraic expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Apparently SciPy is already good enough.

`full_dist_mat = spatial.distance.squareform( spatial.distance.pdist(vects2, metric='cosine'))`

is already optimised. Running 2000 vectors takes 1.3 seconds in jupyter lab on a Macbook pro.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good fit for `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Create your numpy array, then make an iterator of 2-tuples all possible `i` and `j` values. For example with `itertools.combinations`.

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [7]: list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 2))                                                        
Out[7]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

(You should use the length of your vector as the argument to `range`, of course.)

Write the following function:

```
def worker(pair):
    i, j = pair
    rv = False
    if f(X[i],X[j]) < T:
       rv = True
    return (i, j, rv)
```

Create a `Pool`, and run `imap_unordered`:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
for i, j, result in p.imap_unordered(worker, itertools.combinations(range(len(X)), 2)):
    if result:
        print('Good pair:', i, j)
        # do something with the results...
```

This will run as many workers as you CPU has cores.

Comment: thanks. This is very cool. At the end I found scipy distance matrices to be already optimized.